# Is there a way to have utorrent proceed the download queue only if the previous item has been downloaded fully and successfully?

Tags: download, utorrent, queue

Say, I have the following items in the download queue:

item_4 ...Queued
item_3 ...Queued
item_2 ...Queued
item_1 ...Downloading (70%)

The goal is to get **item_2** starting only if **item_1** reached (**100%**) and completed successfully, otherwise, the whole process should be stopped or even better **item_1** should keep trying.

Comment: Can you say why? If you want to make sure the get the first item quickly I think most downloaded can specify a priority.

Comment: @eckes Because sometimes the items are related (ex: series, courses, etc.) and if the later items downloaded without the earlier ones the whole thing is unusable and we just lose gigs of uncompleted material. the later items  usually have a lot more seeders.